# Why does socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname) binds only to local ip address?

Tags: python, sockets, ubuntu, localhost, ip-address

I am writing a socket program to create a simple server. 
When I write `ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` and then I print ip it prints `127.0.1.1`
Why does this keep happening?
My device is connected to a mobile hotspot connection still the ip address remains of a local host.
I am using ubuntu 19.04 OS

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a host has multiple interfaces. It is not a problem is you use a true DNS or a carefully handwritten /etc/host file because then the system will look there to find the translation. But depending on the configuration, the host name can be bound to all the available interfaces, including the loopback one. And `gethostbyname` returns the address of the first of those interfaces in its own order.

To make sure of that, you should use `gethostbyname_ex` which returns a list of all the interfaces, and you should find the hostspot connected one, in addition to the loopback one.

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me.